# How to pass one lookup value to another lookup

Tags: custom-button, account, leads

I have a custom object which is having lookup to both leads and accounts. I have a custom button on lead object which creates custom object record. When i try to populate account lookup in lead object to the custom object account lookup i am facing error

> "RelatedAccount: id value of incorrect type: MALFORMED_ID"

Below is my code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/apex.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/36.0/integration.js")}

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
var item = new sforce.SObject('BackLoopInfo__c');
item.LEA_LeadId__c='{!Lead.Id}';
item.ABFStatus__c='New';
item.RelatedAccount__c ='{!Lead.Account__c}';
alert('{!Lead.Account__c}');
item.OwnerId ='00Gb0000003AyHd';
var result = sforce.connection.create([item]);
alert('Backloop record successfully created');
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/'+result[0].id, true,'', '', '');
```

Below is the screenshot of the lookup field in lead object for account .
[image]

Comment: Does `Lead.Account__c` have a value when you get the error?

Comment: Yes i am getting the lead name only on alert

Comment: Well the name wont do right.. You need the ID.. Maybe you should try `Lead.Account__r.id`

Comment: i tried that too .. I am getting field name does not exist error

Comment: Your lead has lookup to the Account right? Can you post a screenshot of that field in the question?

Comment: posted.. @aslamk

Comment: and RelatedAccount__c is also a lookup to Account only i suppose. If you hardcode an Account id on that line does it work?

Comment: can you try with {!Lead.AccountId__c} @hiSFDC

Comment: Yes @aslam. if i hardoced it works . but for dynamically , it is not working

Comment: I have found it .. I queried and set the account lookup field in a variable and assign it. Thanks for your comments people

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `{!Lead.AccountId__c}`

Comment: This would have been better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: the custom field name is "account__c" not "AccountId__c

Comment: That's right @hiSFDC. When you insert field in your custom button logic, and referencing a lookup field then you can see Account__c(holds name of account) and AccountId__c(holds id of account).